# Debian was hanged in the process

Tags: linux, debian

0

I’m using the Dell Precision Tower 7810 with 2 CPU chips (Intel Geon e5-2696v4 with 22 cores - 44 threads), 256 GB of RAM (8x32 GB), 625 watts of power, and Linux Debian 12. Using the machine, I often get stuck. hanging. I could only move my mouse and not do anything on the computer; I had to restart the computer. Uncomfortable every time. I wondered if it was because the source did not provide enough for the CPU; while using the machine I tested, there was a very hot CPU chip left with almost nothing. I tested and watched the system on the machine and am still getting enough 2 chips, which are 44 cores-88threads.

I am grateful to anyone who can tell me the cause and how to fix this error. Thank you all for viewing my question.

Comment: Do you know the hardware is good? For example, have you run a [memory test](https://www.memtest.org/) to check the RAM?

Comment: `still getting enough` - enough what?

Comment: I've seen recommendations for a 350W power supply for ONE of those chips, you have TWO ... so, not saying you need double, but what GPU do you have

Comment: I'm using GPU NV117 and my RAM is no problem.